# como estabelecer um intervalo numérico para calculo de média

Tags: microsoft-excel

Quero calcular a média de uma variável com a seguinte fórmula: =MÉDIASE(M2:M487;">=20 <25";O2:O487) ou seja quero que os valores de M2 a M487 sejam maiores ou iguais a 20 e menores que 25.

Answer (score 1):

Olá!

Utilize o =MÉDIASES. Ele utiliza mais de um critério para calcular a média. Sua fórmula ficaria assim:

```
=MÉDIASES(O2:O487;M2:M487;">=20";M2:M487;"<25")
```

Abraço!